# Mono resize terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, terminal, mono

In Windows **public static void SetWindowSize(int width, int height)** works fine.

With mono this method is not supported.

Is there a way under Mac OS X with some DllImport to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the final solution that works on Yosemite:

Thanks to RobertN & Chris Page from apple.stackexchange:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33736/can-a-terminal-window-be-resized-with-a-terminal-command/47841#47841?newreg=7290606aabbc45468a3f3ee640cd1d09

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo.Native.ResizeTerm
{
    class MainClass
    {
        [DllImport ("libc")]
        private static extern int system (string exec);


        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            system(@"printf '\e[8;50;100t'");
            Console.WriteLine ("We will be 50 lines and 100 columns in Terminal.app now");
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, that will work for Terminal.app, but not other OS-X apps like iTerm, it will not fault but it will not resize the window either.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I overlooked the fact that 'resize' is coming from XQuartz's (xserver/xterm) package which Apple no longer supplies directly nor maintains; see the XQuartz project for info. See Swell's answer as it uses the term size escape sequence (all that resize is really doing).

You can use system call to 'resize' (**man resize** for details). This is  standard across all(?) xterm and shells (bash/tsh/csh/...)

Assuming you are not using ncurses, but if you are and had a resize handler set, you will get the resize event just like if the user resize the terminal using their mouse.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Demo.Native.ResizeTerm
{
    class MainClass
    {
        [DllImport ("libc")]
        private static extern int system (string exec);


        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            system("resize -s 50 100 > /dev/null");
            Console.WriteLine ("We will be 50 lines and 100 columns in Terminal.app now");
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
```

I added this sample to the CursesSharp repo, github link to source : https://github.com/sushihangover/CursesSharp/blob/368906549512446dc5e97f8c9214c482d6847aac/CursesSharp.Demo/Demo.Native.ResizeTerm/Program.cs

Comment: Apple did not "opensource" resize.  It has been MIT-licensed (and maintained without Apple's assistance) far longer than OSX has been around.  The specific feature of resize (the [-s option](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html)) used in the control sequence was originally documented as a Sun-specific feature, for dtterm.

Comment: The OP's question by the way was about mono, not ncurses.

Comment: I did not mean that Apple wrote xserver, but their version of XQuartz's version of it was handed over/back to XQuartz. updated my answer. Mono? Yes, I wrote my answer in C# running on OS-X/Mono, just stating the fact that because a lot of people use ncurses wrapped in C# running under Mono (as I do myself) and term resizing will cause a callback into the multiple cnurses DotNet libraries.

Comment: @RobertN I have a vanilla install of Yosemite.