# How can I use c# " Console.SetWindowSize()" on MAC visual studio 2022

Tags: c#

How can I use  c# " Console.SetWindowSize()" on MAC visual studio 2022
hen I use Console.SetWindowSize(100, 50) on MAC visual studio 2022, visual studio gave a error info.

I want use  c# " Console.SetWindowSize()" on MAC visual studio 2022.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: According to [Classic Console APIs versus Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/classic-vs-vt#cross-platform-support): _Windows Console APIs are only supported on Windows_.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Windows Console and Terminal Ecosystem Roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ecosystem-roadmap) and  [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [`Console.SetWindowSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setwindowsize), you will see this, underneath "Exceptions":

> `PlatformNotSupportedException`
>
> The current operating system is not Windows.

This method can only be used on Windows, and will throw an exception on any other platform.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522500/mono-resize-terminal-on-mac-os-x) for a possible workaround.